# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when using CSharpScript in Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, csharpscript

I'm trying to use CSharpScript in a Blazor wasm application, testing with a simple `EvaluateAsync`:

```
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>("1 + 1");
```

Throws: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/mscorlib.dll"`

I'm using Blazor wasm 3.2.0-preview3.20168.3

**Edit**:
Here's the full code in `index.razor`:

```
@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing...");
        var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>("1 + 1");
    }
}
```

And here's the console output:

```
Initializing...
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find file "/mscorlib.dll"
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/mscorlib.dll"
File name: '/mscorlib.dll'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) <0x3ba83f8 + 0x002b4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) <0x3b987a0 + 0x0001c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) <0x3b986d0 + 0x0000a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream (System.String path) [0x0001c] in /_/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/FileSystem/FileUtilities.cs:416 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReferenceProperties properties, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentationProvider documentation) [0x0005a] in /_/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs:329 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in /_/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs:271 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.GetReferencesForCompilation (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag diagnostics, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference languageRuntimeReferenceOpt) [0x0001a] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:252 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScriptCompiler.CreateSubmission (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script script) [0x00021] in /_/src/Scripting/CSharp/CSharpScriptCompiler.cs:40 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.GetCompilation () [0x00008] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:144 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1[T].GetExecutor (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00008] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:361 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1[T].RunAsync (System.Object globals, System.Func`2[T,TResult] catchException, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0001b] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:465 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1[T].RunAsync (System.Object globals, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:439 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.RunAsync[T] (System.String code, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions options, System.Object globals, System.Type globalsType, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in /_/src/Scripting/CSharp/CSharpScript.cs:93 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync[T] (System.String code, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions options, System.Object globals, System.Type globalsType, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in /_/src/Scripting/CSharp/CSharpScript.cs:123 
  at ScriptPlayground.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync () [0x0008a] in C:\Users\sarma\source\repos\ScriptPlayground\Pages\Index.razor:17 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x36de968 + 0x0013a> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Edit 2:
After digging deeper into the issue, we traced it down to these lines in `Script.cs`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the references that need to be assigned to the compilation.
/// This can be different than the list of references defined by the <see cref="ScriptOptions"/> instance.
/// </summary>
internal ImmutableArray<MetadataReference> GetReferencesForCompilation(
    CommonMessageProvider messageProvider,
    DiagnosticBag diagnostics,
    MetadataReference languageRuntimeReferenceOpt = null)
{
    var resolver = Options.MetadataResolver;
    var references = ArrayBuilder<MetadataReference>.GetInstance();
    try
    {
        if (Previous == null)
        {
            var corLib = MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
            references.Add(corLib);
```

No matter what options we pass, this will always be called on compilation, `MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal` tries to load a file from disk. So it appears that loading assemblies from disk is hardcoded into the process. We're looking for a clean way of overriding this.

We were already successful in loading assemblies from streams using HttpClient:

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    var name = assembly.GetName().Name + ".dll";
    references.Add(
        MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(
            await this.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("/_framework/_bin/" + name)));
}
```

But this doesn't matter as long as CSharpScript is loading another set of assemblies during compilation from disk

Comment: I added the console output

Comment: We were able to do something like this, but the issue remains since CSharpScript is loading assemblies using `File.OpenRead(path)` to load some compilation-time assemblies. Please check the second edit

Comment: That would mean CSharpScript is just not suitable for Blazor.

Comment: Yes, that's what I concluded. I'm moving on to compiling the code as an assembly and loading it in the current domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CsharpScript` API unfortunately has been built with a dependency on looking up assemblies on the local filesystem. If you dig deep enough in the `MetadataReference.CreateFromStream` source, you will see the culprit being a call to `File.OpenRead()`

I spent some time myself looking into any possible extensibility of the API where one could supply an alternative assembly resolution strategy. There is a path via the supply of a custom `MetaDataReferenceResolver` in the `ScriptOptions` however the baking in of the line you discovered

```
 var corLib = MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

effectively creates the hard dependency on the file system which kills the idea.

The resolution of `mscorlib` is done this way above, but then all other asemblies use the `Options.MetaDataReferences` list. Why I have no idea....

As a pure hack I even had a crack at capturing the call to `File.OpenRead()` and returing my own `stream` from `HttpClient`. The injection works in a desktop process, but something was going wrong in wasm. In the end I gave up too in favour of rolling an alternative such as [this approach](https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.Samples.BlazorCSharpInteractive/tree/master) or [this one](https://www.samprof.com/2018/12/15/compile-csharp-and-blazor-inside-browser-en).

Here was the trial hack for anyone who is interested.

```
    //Using the Pose library https://github.com/tonerdo/pose
    var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(navigationManager.BaseUri) };
    Shim fileShim = Shim.Replace(() => System.IO.File.OpenRead(Is.A<string>())).With(delegate (string assembly)
    {
        var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(assembly, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        client.GetStreamAsync($"_framework/_bin/{assembly}").Result.CopyTo(fs);
        return fs;
    });

    PoseContext.Isolate(() => Text = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>("hello").Result, fileShim);
```

HTH

Comment: We eventually went with a similar approach as well, we're compiling the code in a wrapped method/class inside the assembly and loading it. Fortunately, in our case, we can get away with compiling only once during application startup.

Comment: in .Net5 "_framework/_bin" becomes "_framework/"